# how to store value in dict correctly?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a code which brings AWS RDS details:

```
def instance_name():
    mylist=['ap-southeast-2']
    for region in mylist:
        conn=boto.rds.connect_to_region(region)
        try:
            mydb={}
            instances=conn.get_all_dbinstances()
            for instance in instances:
               #mydb.append(instance.id)
               #print instance.id
               #print instance.instance_class
               mydb['rds_name']=instance.id
               mydb['rds_type']=instance.instance_class
            return mydb
        except:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
   x = instance_name()
   print x
```

but this only print the last RDS instance in the list.

```
{'rds_name': u'syd01-jumper-upgrad-shared', 'rds_type': u'db.t2.medium'}
```

Now if you look at the code, i have created a dictionary & want to store the rds something like this:

```
{
 {'rds_name': u'syd01-jumper-upgrad-shared'
          {
          'rds_type': u'db.t2.medium'
          }
 }
 {
  'rds_name': u'some_other_db'
          {
          'rds_type': u'db.t3.large'
          }
  }
}           
.
.
```

I.e i want my 'rds_name' to be main value and the 'rds_type' as subclass. how to do so ?

Comment: The data structure you want just doesn't exist...`{'rds_name': u'syd01-jumper-upgrad-shared'
          {
          'rds_type': u'db.t2.medium'
          }
 }` doesn't make any sense for a dictionary

Comment: In dictionary, keys are unique and you are re-writing the value of key in each iteration. Hence you are getting only last results. Your program is returning dictionary of dictionaries. You have to formulate a method to save it. For more on dictionary in Python, please refer basic tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: @m_callens , oh okay i understand,, but hod do i do what i intend to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

you're just updating your dictionary in the loop, so you get the last value.

That said, the stucture you want to create is a set of dictionaries, which is not possible because dictionaries are not *hashable* (means that they cannot be converted to a hash key for a set or a dictionary key)

You want a list of dictionaries, and to do that, one line is enough using list comprehension to build your dictionaries in a list:

```
return [{'rds_name':instance.id,'rds_type':instance.instance_class} for instance in conn.get_all_dbinstances()]
```

Which is equivalent to (but faster than):

```
mydb = []
for instance in conn.get_all_dbinstances():
   mydb.append({'rds_name':instance.id,'rds_type':instance.instance_class})
return mydb
```

Aside: *never* do `try` and `except: pass`: you're masking all the errors that could occur, including undefined variables, etc... Let the program run, and trap exceptions only if needed and only the needed exception type(s).

Comment: oh okay, can u open up the list comprehension please to let me know better , i am really new

Comment: also what do u mean by `hashable`

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Class](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

```
class Rds:
    def __init__(self, name, type):
        self.Name = name
        self.Type = type
```